# Jquery Autocomplete selected id not getting saved

Tags: jquery, jquery-autocomplete

I am trying to get the selected value from the jquery autocomplete for some reason I am not able to get the id.  I saw a solution here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/152558/jQuery-UI-Autocomplete-with-ID but my data returns like below  How should I get the id saved?

**My data**

```
[{"id":3,"homename":"DCosta"}]
```

**My code**

```
$("#lastname").autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
     var term = request.term;
     if (term in cache) {
         response(cache[term]);
        return;
     }
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: someurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "Name": request.term},
        success: function (result) {
              var Surnames = JSON.parse(result.data);
              cache[term] = ($.map(Surnames, function (item) {
               return {
                          label: item.homename,
                          //value: item.id  //<== if I do like this the id show in the text box which I do now want
                          value: item.homename //<== this shows correctly but the id is not accessable
                       }
                 }));
             response(cache[term]);
         },

         error: function (a, b, c) {
                       debugger;
         }
      });

      },
        select: function (event, ui) {
         self.Surname(ui.item.value); // save selected value
          console.log(self.Surname());  // shows ID if value: item.id or just the name

     },
           minLength: 2
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a hidden field to store your `id` (let's give it an id of `myhiddenid`) and set your autocomplete field's value to the label returned from your function. Adding `return false;` will cancel the event's default behavior

> The default action is to replace the text field's value with the value of the selected item.

```
var myhiddenid = $("#myhiddenid");
var lastname = $("#lastname");

lastname.autocomplete({
     source: function (request, response) {
     var term = request.term;
     if (term in cache) {
         response(cache[term]);
        return;
     }
      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: someurl,
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { "Name": request.term},
        success: function (result) {
              var Surnames = JSON.parse(result.data);
              cache[term] = ($.map(Surnames, function (item) {
               return {
                          label: item.homename,
                          value: item.id
                       }
                 }));
             response(cache[term]);
         },

         error: function (a, b, c) {
                       debugger;
         }
      });

      },
        focus: function (event, ui) {
         lastname.val(ui.item.label);
         myhiddenid.val(ui.item.value);
         return false;

     },
        select: function (event, ui) {
         lastname.val(ui.item.label);
         myhiddenid.val(ui.item.value);
         self.Surname(ui.item.value);
         console.log(self.Surname());
         return false;    
     },
           minLength: 2
});
```

Comment: the moment I add this  value: item.id the text box shows the id.  I added this too  $('#lastname').val(ui.item.label); and assume it will show the label value in the text box but nothing happens.  Adding this myhiddenid.val(ui.item.value); give undefined

Comment: Did you create a hidden input on your screen? (`<input type="hidden" id="myhiddenid" />`)

Comment: Ah missed that will try and let you know

Comment: still the id shows up in the text box am I missing anything.  This is what I did  $('#lastname').val(ui.item.label);
self.Surname(ui.item.value); // save selected value
$('#myhiddenid').val(ui.item.value);

Comment: @Adrian - I updated the answer. I included a `focus:` event as well and pointed out the default behavior of the events. Since you want the label and not the value to be shown, you'll need to do this manually (with the `.val()` lines we've done) and then `return false;`

Comment: I did not add the focus part and it still works thanks